# Need to return shortcode text instead of the output

Tags: filters, shortcode, hooks

Is there a way I can return the shortcode text instead of the output.

My code function is hooked into 'the_content' and I know if my function contain shortcode it will automatically generate the output. I just want to output shortcode text e.g [gallery]

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'show_on_front', 10 );
function show_on_front( $content ) {
   $content .= 'this is example of shortcode : [gallery]';
   return $content;
}
```

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to use a shortcode to display shortcodes :)

```
add_shortcode('SH','shortcode_display_handler');
function shortcode_display_handler($atts = array(),$content=null){
    $content = str_replace("[","&#91;",$content);
    $content = str_replace("]","&#93;",$content);
    return $content;
}
```

Usage:

```
[SH] [gallery] [/SH]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to literally echo "this is example of shortcode : [gallery]" with no shortcode processing then give your filter a very high number for a priority:

`add_filter( 'the_content', 'show_on_front', 1000 );`

That way, it runs after the shortcode processing function runs.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm somehow misunderstanding the Question, you could just change `[gallery]` to `[[gallery]]`.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'show_on_front', 10 );
function show_on_front( $content ) {
   $content .= 'this is example of shortcode : [[gallery]]';
   return $content;
}
```